# listen multiple clusters at the same time is not possible on pusher_client

Tags: flutter, pusher

I'm not sure if it's a bug. I'm just looking for an answer to this use case.

In my application, I need to listen to two clusters simultaneously, and this is not possible because PusherClient is a singleton class and only allows you to pass one cluster on PusherOptions. Could someone help me with some ideas on how to solve this problem?

I'm trying to listen to more than one cluster simultaneously using PusherClient in my Flutter application